# Swift - Have scroll view fit the entire screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

My scroll view does not fit the screen entirely. There is a black border at the top and on the left side. It looks like this.[image]

Here is the code I use to create the scrollView:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Map 1.png"))
scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will remove "Adjust Scroll View Insets" from `UIViewController`

[image]

Comment: I unchecked that box and it did not do anything

Answer (score -1):

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Map 1.png"))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill       
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width  , height: self.scrollView.frame.height)

scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width       
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

view.addSubview(scrollView)
```